# Play Audio from raw folder in Android

Tags: android, media-player

I tried to play an audio file from res/raw folder, here is the code, which I used to play the file, this is not generating any error and my device volume is max, but not getting any sound. I tried MP3 and WAV files.

```
    public void btnPlay(View v) {               
        MediaPlayer mPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(con, R.raw.horse);            
        try {
            mPlayer.start();            

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(con,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting following message on LogCat after start

```
02-07 17:50:42.331: I/MediaPlayer(16345): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
```

Help me to resolve this issue and it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("name of sound" , "name of folder", getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), resID);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy way to play audio from the raw folder, try this code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mplayer;
    public void play(View view) {
        mplayer.start();
    }
    public void pause(View view) {
        mplayer.pause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        mplayer =MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ab);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi earthKing JAD hav, welcome. Please consider adding more information.